# SD card initializing failed on arduino using 7'' lcd with CTE shield.

Tags: arduino, sd-card

There seems to be a problem in reading the SD card (2gb FAT) using the CTE shield.

I am using a Arduino Mega CTE shield to attach the SD card but it shows initializing failed.

I am using the CardInfo code from the #SD library. I have tried changing the pin to 45 but to no avail.

Could any1 help in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

What is CTE shield? Provide a link. Do you know which pin is the chip select for this shield? What is pin 45?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/SainSmart-TFT-Shield-Arduino-Mega2560/dp/B00INM6BZA    I am new to arduino and I cant confirm which pin is the chip select as its not working. Could you please help me.